# No puedo encontrar el error en mi codigo Java

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

Soy nueva en Java, no corre en cdm, ni en Eclipse, lo he revisado y no puedo identificar los errores, aun no puedo ni hacer los metodos porque he estado probando y no funciona, dice que hay 26 errores

```
public class Vendedor {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
    String nombre = "";
    int sTrabajadas = 0;
    int vVentas = 0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del trabajador");

    nombre = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese las semanas trabajadas");
    sTrabajadas = entrada.nextInt;
    System.out.println("Ingrese valor de articulos vendidos");
    vVentas = entrada.nextInt;

    if (vVentas>0){
        public int comision = vVentas * 9%;
        System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
    }
    else {System.out.prinln("El trabajador "+ nombre + "no registra comision");
    }
}
```

Los errores son

> Vendedor.java:7: error:  expected
>   System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del trabajador");
>                     ^ Vendedor.java:7: error: illegal start of type System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del trabajador");
>                      ^ Vendedor.java:8: error:  expected nombre = entrada.nextLine();
>         ^ Vendedor.java:9: error:  expected System.out.println("Ingrese las semanas trabajadas");
>                     ^ Vendedor.java:9: error: illegal start of type System.out.println("Ingrese las semanas trabajadas");
>                      ^ Vendedor.java:10: error:  expected sTrabajadas = entrada.nextInt;
>              ^ Vendedor.java:11: error:  expected System.out.println("Ingrese valor de articulos vendidos");
>                     ^ Vendedor.java:11: error: illegal start of type System.out.println("Ingrese valor de articulos vendidos");
>                      ^ Vendedor.java:12: error:  expected vVentas = entrada.nextInt;
>          ^ Vendedor.java:14: error: illegal start of type if (vVentas>0){ ^ Vendedor.java:14: error:  expected if
>   (vVentas>0){
>              ^ Vendedor.java:14: error: ';' expected if (vVentas>0){
>               ^ Vendedor.java:14: error: illegal start of type if (vVentas>0){
>                ^ Vendedor.java:14: error:  expected if (vVentas>0){
>                 ^ Vendedor.java:14: error: ';' expected if (vVentas>0){
>                  ^ Vendedor.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
>           public int comision = vVentas * 9%;
>                                             ^ Vendedor.java:16: error:  expected
>       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
>                         ^ Vendedor.java:16: error: illegal start of type
>       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
>                          ^ Vendedor.java:16: error: ')' expected
>       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
>                                                   ^ Vendedor.java:16: error: ';' expected
>       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
>                                                    ^ Vendedor.java:16: error: illegal start of type
>       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
>                                                            ^ Vendedor.java:16: error:  expected
>       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
>                                                             ^ Vendedor.java:16: error: ';' expected
>       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
>                                                                   ^ Vendedor.java:16: error:  expected
>       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
>                                                                              ^ Vendedor.java:18: error: class, interface, or enum expected else
>   {System.out.prinln("El trabajador "+ nombre + "no registra comision");
>   ^ Vendedor.java:19: error: class, interface, or enum expected } ^ 26
>   errors

Comment: Puedes por favor agregar los errores que te aparecen? así considero será mas simple encontrar las soluciones

Comment: @Aprendiz Disculpa, ahí los puse

Comment: No te preocupes no hay problema, lo que agregas ayudará mucho a que quienes conocen de Java te auxilien mas rápido, suerte

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios fallos, el resultado del codigo sin fallos sería lo siguiente, con comentarios donde tuviste cada fallo.

```java
//Debes de importar la clase Scanner con la siguiente linea
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vendedor {

    //Debes tener un metodo main dentro de la clase Vendedor, dentro estara el codigo a ejecutar:
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
        String nombre = "";
        int sTrabajadas = 0;
        int vVentas = 0;
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del trabajador");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese las semanas trabajadas");
        //nextInt() le faltaba los parentesis
        sTrabajadas = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese valor de articulos vendidos");
        //nextInt() le faltaba los parentesis
        vVentas = entrada.nextInt();


    if (vVentas>0){
       //No hace falta poner "public", y el 9% debería ser "9/100" 
       int comision = vVentas * 9 /100;
       System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
    }else{
       //pusiste mal "println"
       System.out.println("El trabajador "+ nombre + "no registra comision");
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Te pasaste, en serio, me cuesta reconocer los errores aun, aunque ahora que lo pienso eran muy evidentes, gracias.

Comment: No olvides marcar la pregunta que te ayudó a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

dejo comentarios en tu código:

```
public class Vendedor {
    //Falta el método "main"
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
    String nombre = "";
    int sTrabajadas = 0;
    int vVentas = 0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del trabajador");

    nombre = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese las semanas trabajadas");
    sTrabajadas = entrada.nextInt;//Faltan los paréntesis
    System.out.println("Ingrese valor de articulos vendidos");
    vVentas = entrada.nextInt;//Faltan paréntesis

    if (vVentas>0){
        //El encapsulamiento es perteneciente a la clase de ahí que no puedes declarar comisión como publica en un metodo o en este caso en una condicional
        public int comision = vVentas * 9%; // el % se considera el operador de modulo n, seria 0.09
        System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es " + comision);
    }
    else {System.out.prinln("El trabajador "+ nombre + "no registra comision");// Falta una "t" en el println
    }
}
```

Corrigiendo tu código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vendedor {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
        String nombre = "";
        int sTrabajadas = 0;
        int vVentas = 0;
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del trabajador: ");

        nombre = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese las semanas trabajadas: ");
        sTrabajadas = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese valor de articulos vendidos: ");
        vVentas = entrada.nextInt();

        if (vVentas > 0){
            double comision = vVentas * 0.09;
            System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + "es: " + comision);
        }
        else {System.out.println("El trabajador "+ nombre + "no registra comision");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Te falta poner la clase `main()`. Es necesario para iniciar cualquier programa java:

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

Te falta poner los `()` a `nextInt` ya que se tratan de métodos.

Tu código debería quedar así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vendedor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
        String nombre = "";
        int sTrabajadas = 0;
        int vVentas = 0;
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del trabajador");

        nombre = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese las semanas trabajadas");
        sTrabajadas = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese valor de articulos vendidos");
        vVentas = entrada.nextInt();

        if (vVentas>0){
            int comision = vVentas * 9 / 100;
            System.out.println("La comision semanal de "+ nombre + " es " + comision);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("El trabajador "+ nombre + " no registra comision");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: int comision = vVentas * 9 / 100;

Comment: Buena observacion. Gracias por el aviso!

Comment: Gracias, te pasaste, por mas que tenia los errores en frente no podía verlos, muchas gracias. Una pregunta, la clase main no la puse ya que la hice en una clase aparte, segun mi profesor "se ve mas ordenado y se evitan errores", ¿es tan necesario hacerlo por separado?

Comment: Para proyecto pequeños o programas para ir aprendiendo a programar no es tan necesario. Pero a medida que éstos crecen, se vuelve mas complejos, es recomendable poner cada clase aparte.